# std::shared_ptr in one writer many reader design is thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr

In a mutithreading server, one thread(writer) update data periodically from a database and other thread(readers) process user's request with this data.

I try to use a read/write lock to meet this request, but the performance is so bad, so it's needed to find something else.

I read from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr, it's says:

All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization **even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object**.

Then after some research, I use to std::shared_ptr to do it. The code is like something below.

```
// this class is singleton
class DataManager{
public:
    // all the reader thread use this method to get data and release shared_ptr 
    // at the end of user's request
    std::shared_ptr<Data> get_main_ptr(){
        return _main_data;
    }
private:
    // data1
    std::shared_ptr<Data> _main_data;
    // data2
    std::shared_ptr<Data> _back_data;

    // read database, write data in to _data
    void update_data(std::shared_ptr<Data> _data);

    // this function called at a separate thread every 10 min
    bool reload_data(){
        // write data in back pointer
        update_data(_back_data);

        //save the _main_data
        std::shared_ptr<Data> old_ptr = _main_data;

        //exchange pointer, reader thread hold the copy of _main_data
        _main_data = _back_data;

        // wait until reader threads release all copy of _main_data
        while(old_ptr.use_count() != 1) {
            sleep(5);
        }

        // clear the data
        old_ptr->clear();
        _back_data = old_ptr;
        return;
}

}
```

This method seems worked in production environment. but I'm not quite sure and don't understand the thread safe level of shared_ptr. Is there problem in this method? Or other suggestions to meet my request

Comment: The shared_ptr is thread safe.  The owned object's thread safety has no guarantees.

Comment: How often do you update the data?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you re-assign a `shared_ptr` which is shared between thread:

```
_main_data = _back_data;
```

If another thread reads or copies `_main_data` simultaneously it may get a corrupted copy.

Assigning to a `shared_ptr` is not thread-safe because `shared_ptr` contains two pointer members and they cannot be both updated atomically. See [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

> If multiple threads of execution access the same `shared_ptr` without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of `shared_ptr` then a data race will occur;

To fix that race condition the code needs to use [`atomic_store`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic):

```
atomic_store(&_main_data, _back_data);
```

And the readers must do:

```
auto main_data = atomic_load(&_main_data);
```

[Notes section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) is helpful:

> These functions are typically implemented using mutexes, stored in a global hash table where the pointer value is used as the key.
>
> To avoid data races, once a shared pointer is passed to any of these functions, it cannot be accessed non-atomically. In particular, you cannot dereference such a `shared_ptr` without first atomically loading it into another `shared_ptr` object, and then dereferencing through the second object.
>
> The Concurrency TS offers atomic smart pointer classes `atomic_shared_ptr` and `atomic_weak_ptr` as a replacement for the use of these functions.
>
> Since C++20: These functions were deprecated in favor of the specializations of the `std::atomic` template: `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` and `std::atomic<std::weak_ptr>`.

---

Also, you should make `Data` destructor do all the cleanup, so that you do not have to wait until reader threads release `_main_data` to clean it up manually.

---

Alternatively, you can use `std::atomic` and `boost::intrusive_ptr` to make updating the data pointer thread-safe, atomic, wait-free and leak-free.

The benefit of using `boost::intrusive_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr` is that the former can be thread-safely created from a plain pointer because the atomic reference count is stored inside the object.

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

#include <boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ref_counter.hpp>

struct Data
    : boost::intrusive_ref_counter<Data, boost::thread_safe_counter>
{};

using DataPtr = boost::intrusive_ptr<Data>;

class DataAccessor
{
    std::atomic<Data*> data_ = 0;

public:
    ~DataAccessor() {
        DataPtr{data_.load(std::memory_order_acquire), false}; // Destroy data_.
    }

    DataPtr get_data() const {
        return DataPtr{data_.load(std::memory_order_acquire)};
    };

    void set_data(DataPtr new_data) {
        DataPtr old_data{data_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed), false}; // Destroy data_.
        data_.store(new_data.detach(), std::memory_order_release);
    }
};

int main() {
    DataAccessor da;

    DataPtr new_data{new Data};
    da.set_data(new_data);
    DataPtr old_data = da.get_data();
    std::cout << (new_data == old_data) << '\n';
}
```

`valgrind` run:

```
$ valgrind ./test
==21502== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==21502== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==21502== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==21502== Command: ./test
==21502== 
1
==21502== 
==21502== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21502==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21502==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 73,736 bytes allocated
==21502== 
==21502== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==21502== 
==21502== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21502== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But actually, every reader thread have different copy of _main_data(throught get_main_ptr() function ) and the update thread access _main_ptr directly, I think It's the situation in that url. The reader and writer thread own different shared_ptr instances and these instances share ownership of the same object. It this still a chance to get a corrupted data?

Comment: @antonyzhang `get_main_ptr` loads `_main_data` and if you call it simultaneously with `_main_data = _back_data;` you get a data race. Your readers probably call `get_main_ptr` periodically to get the new value of `_main_data`.

Comment: That is what I excepted, reader thread call **get_main_ptr** to get new value or old value, after **_main_data = _back_data** reader thread will not get the old value, then after the while loop, no reader thread hold the old value, it is safe to clear old value. I wonder if there is a race condition that the shared_ptr reference count increase by 1 but the raw pointer not get exchanged?

Comment: @antonyzhang I struggle with your descriptions. Post complete code of your producer and consumers.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Running your program with thread sanitizer throws up errors.
[Test app for reference](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qY8czrTEq)

Comment: @saai63 gcc sanitizer is broken in compiler explorer. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WerszWrxq

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: My bad! Didn't check with clang.

Answer (score 1):

You skipped this part:

> If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without
>   synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member
>   function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur

shared_ptr is just a container for your pointer. It's not thread-safe. You can make it, but it's easier to use locks.

Comment: the = operator and read in different shared_ptr instances hold the same raw pointer is safe?

Comment: No, the assignment operator is not const. You can get an assignment and read at the same time, resulting in an incorrect value.